# How to execute external Python script with a program coded in Haxe?

Tags: python, json, haxe

I have a Haxe program and I need to retrieve data from Wordnik API.
Here are the list of supported platform in Wordnik:
http://developer.wordnik.com/#!/libraries

I have no experience in all of these languages supported by Wordnik. However, I think Python is the most feasible way to connect Wordnik API into my Haxe program because Python is a scripting language and can be executed from terminal command.

Perhaps, something like Haxe program execute the Python WITH some parameters. Then the Python script retrieve data from Wordnik and then compile it into a JSON or .txt file. Finally return back to Haxe program to parse the JSON or .txt file. I am not sure how this thing can work, hence I am looking for guidance here :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing to look out for is using the [Python 3 version](https://github.com/wordnik/wordnik-python3) of the library, instead of the [Python 2.7 one](https://github.com/wordnik/wordnik-python) which is linked to on that overview page. Haxe's Python target [only supports version 3 or higher](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/4195).

There shouldn't be a need for a Python program serving as an interface between Haxe and the Wordnik API - you could write [externs](http://haxe.org/manual/lf-externs.html) describing the interface to just use it directly from Haxe. An `extern` for a very simple class, [`wordnik.models.Label`](https://github.com/wordnik/wordnik-python3/blob/master/wordnik/models/Label.py), could look like this:

```haxe
package wordnik.models;

@:pythonImport("wordnik.models.Label", "Label")
extern class Label
{
    public var text:String;
    public var type:String;

    public function new() 
    {
    }
}
```

With that, you can then use the API from Haxe:

```haxe
package;

import python.Lib;
import wordnik.models.Label;

class Main 
{
    static function main() 
    {
        var label = new Label();
        label.text = "Test";
        trace(label.text);
    }
}
```

You can find a lot of examples of Python externs in [the Haxe standard library](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/tree/development/std/python/lib). It also has wrappers for things that are a bit more complex to express, like [`KwArgs`](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/development/std/python/KwArgs.hx).

Comment: Can I target C++ with this or just Python?

Comment: It returns this error if go compile to C++. ./src/Main.cpp:32:3: error: ‘Label’ was not declared in this scope.

Comment: Are you targeting C++? It sounded like you were going for Python. Python externs only work on the Python target afaik.

Comment: I use OpenFL to compile my project to Linux executable.

Comment: Soundas like you want a regular haxe/openfl c++ app that calls an *external* python script? You could call python directly via the process command: http://api.haxe.org/sys/io/Process.html